# iOS13 crash when back to ViewController with right navigationItem

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, backbarbuttonitem

My app running on iPad now, it has split viewController and masterVC is navigationViewController it has root UITableViewController and als has a right navigationItem.

ok crash step is .. here

1. On UISplitViewController touch tableViewCell on master UITableViewController
2. Next ViewController will pushed on tableViewController over master area of UISplitViewController
3. go back to UITableViewController
4. now it's crash

only happens on iPadOS13 Device ..

I made symbolic break point with call stack to find who has responsibility of crash
but It's really hard to know what is the cause crash

and also backBarButton default arrow image has disappeared only iPadOS13 device help me plz..

```
Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x000000018756fca4 in -[UIGraphicsRenderer initWithBounds:format:]()
#1  0x000000018756d584 in -[UIGraphicsImageRenderer initWithSize:format:] ()
#2  0x0000000187064388 in ___slideTransitionFadeMaskImage_block_invoke_2 ()
#3  0x000000010b3b2c04 in _dispatch_client_callout () 
#4  0x000000010b3b44f4 in _dispatch_once_callout ()
#5  0x00000001870642c0 in _slideTransitionFadeMaskImage ()
#6  0x000000018707a99c in _performAdditionalTitleViewClipping ()
#7  0x000000018707d9e8 in -[_UINavigationBarTransitionContextPop _prepareContentView] ()
#8  0x000000018707e2d4 in -[_UINavigationBarTransitionContextPop prepare] ()
#9  0x0000000187089960 in -[_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS _performAnimationWithTransitionCompletion:transition:] ()
#10 0x00000001870373b8 in -[UINavigationBar _popNavigationItemWithTransitionAssistant:] ()
#11 0x0000000187037028 in -[UINavigationBar _popNavigationItemWithTransition:] ()
#12 0x0000000187293b14 in ___popViewControllerNormal_block_invoke ()
#13 0x0000000187293e44 in ___popViewControllerNormal_block_invoke.2830 ()
#14 0x0000000187281748 in __98-[UINavigationController _shouldSkipHostedRefreshControlUpdateSchedulingDeferredUpdateIfNecessary]_block_invoke ()
#15 0x0000000187283164 in -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] ()
#16 0x00000001872842ec in -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] ()
#17 0x0000000187268060 in -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] ()
#18 0x0000000187da7270 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] ()
#19 0x000000018a2935f8 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
#20 0x000000018a297e28 in CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#21 0x000000018a2a3894 in CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#22 0x000000018a1ec9f0 in CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double) ()
#23 0x000000018a216890 in CA::Transaction::commit() ()
#24 0x000000018a217284 in CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) ()
#25 0x000000018388bc48 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#26 0x0000000183886b34 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#27 0x0000000183887100 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#28 0x00000001838868bc in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#29 0x000000018d6f2328 in GSEventRunModal ()
#30 0x000000018791c6d4 in UIApplicationMain ()
#31 0x0000000104606534 in main at /Users/user/Documents/studio-644-ios/Classes/AppDelegate.swift:31
#32 0x0000000183711460 in start ()
```